# Snake Game - Collision I have no idea

Tags: c++, sfml

I write the game "snake" and I have a problem with body snake, namely the Snake head is saved to the list

`std::list<sf::RectangleShape> listaSnake;` (library SFML)

and I don't know how I can do collision when the position Snake head will be equal position body. I only know how to do collision between the head and the tail.
My idea:

```
auto HeadSnake = listaSnake.front();
auto tail = listaSnake.back();
    if (HeadSnake.getPosition().x == tail.getPosition().x && HeadSnake.getPosition().y == tail.getPosition().y) cout << "works!";
```

Comment: 1) `==` is a very bad idea, since those values are floats

2) Just iterate thorugh the list and use `sf::Rect::intersects`

Comment: It is better to save the positions in integer coordinates which will make this code simpler and not prune to floating point error. When shown to screen, convert them to floats.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a [`sf::RectangleShape`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1RectangleShape.php) you can construct a `sf::FloatRect` (which is just [`sf::Rect<float>`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Rect.php)) and then call [`sf::FloatRect::intersects`](http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Rect.php#a566740c8f58e01bb052266f47e7e1011) between two `sf::FloatRect`.

As an example:

```
sf::RectangleShape a(..);
sf::RectangleShape b(..);

sf::FloatRect a_rect(a.getPosition(), a.getSize());
sf::FloatRect b_rect(b.getPosition(), b.getSize());

if (a_rect.intersects(b_rect)) {
    // ...
}
```